# jquery/javascript function work in the firebug console but not on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Long story short i need to edit a textarea after it was created by a wordpress plugin, i can set the id and default value, but i can't set events or anything else, i want the default value to disappear after the user clicks to enter the phone number.

I have tried several ways of doing this without luck, some are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){    
    // Your code goes here    

function clearOnInitialFocus ("telid01") {
var clearedOnce = false;
document.getElementById("telid01").onfocus = (function () {
if (clearedOnce == false) {
this.value = '';
clearedOnce = true;
}
})
}
window.onload = function() { clearOnInitialFocus('telid01');}

});
    </script>
```

Also tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
document.getElementById('telid01').addEventListener('focus', function() {
   this.value = "";
});
});
    </script>
```

this works in the console but not on page load:

```
document.getElementById('telid01').addEventListener('focus', function() {
   this.value = "";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using function parameters in a strange way.
I've tried the following code that is based on yours and it works fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){    
    // Your code goes here    
        var clearedOnce = false;
        document.getElementById("myTest").onfocus = 
        function () {
            if (clearedOnce == false) {
                this.value = '';
                clearedOnce = true;
            }
        };
    });
    </script>

</head> 
<body>
    <input id="myTest" value="placeholder" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't this example work by itself in a separate .html file? Can you try different browsers?

Comment: yes it works!!! thanks man! probably had to add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yeah, okay, but you have overridden the 'onfocus' event. If you use my method, you can have more than one 'focus' event, and you can attach the event even if the textarea hasn't been inserted into the DOM yet. But if the problem was that you didn't even include jQuery then...

Comment: it was included before in the document thats why i didn't include it again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you may as well use jQuery's event binding, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    var clearedOnce = false;
    $(this).on('focus', '#telid01', function () {
        if (!clearedOnce) {
            $(this).val('');
            clearedOnce = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: If you attach the event to 'document' then pass the id as a selector to on() it should work, and should be able to attach the event even without the field existing on the page yet. See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I can't initialize the textarea like that because its done by a wordpress plugin.. i only can set the id, class and default value.

Comment: I've tried this code and it works fine. So your problem is probably caused by something else. Try inserting `Alert()` to different places in JS code to see what is actually executing.

Comment: tried <script type="text/javascript"> Alert() </script> and it didn't work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, I've modified it.

Comment: function names are case-sensitive. It is "alert()" not "Alert()"